# Searching data from database using checkbox list for a ecommerce website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello sir i wanna search the data using checkbox aur checkboxlist like if i select two checkbox then i wanna to get the data of both the checkbox id's this code is giving me only one data at a time. please give me a demo code for this type of query.

private void checkboxlistbind()
    {

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\FlagBits\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\checkboxlist\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    string query = "select * from student where id='" + CheckBox1.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = dr;
    GridView1.DataBind();



}
private void checkboxlistbind2()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\FlagBits\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\checkboxlist\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    string query = "select * from student where id='" + CheckBox2.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = dr;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}


protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        checkboxlistbind();
    }

}
protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
    {
        checkboxlistbind();
        checkboxlistbind2();
    }
```

Comment: That code is susceptible to SQL injection; DO NOT CONCATENATE user input into SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your checkboxlist and test the selected value for each item and build a string containing each of your options.

```
    string queryparam = '';
      for (int i=0; i<checkboxlist1.Items.Count; i++) {
         if (checkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected)
            {  queryparam  += (queryparam.Length = 0) ? "id = " + checkboxlist1.Items[i].Text : " or id = "  checkboxlist1.Items[i].Text }
      }
```

This should give you an idea to start with.